# Why does this Pandas csv import fail?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to import the following csv text:

```
name, favorites, age, other_hobbies
joe, "[madonna, elvis, u2]", 28, "[football, cooking]"
mary, "[lady gaga, adele]", 36, "[]"
```

With the following `pandas` command

```
file_name = "new_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep =",")
print(df)
```

And I get this result:

```
                             name  favorites          age  other_hobbies
joe   "[madonna    elvis     u2]"         28   "[football      cooking]"
mary  "[lady gaga  adele]"     36       "[]"          NaN            NaN
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get `pandas` to read this properly?

Comment: How is your file generated? Is it hand-crafted or is it saved by some program?

Comment: did you create this file? you should use a different separator if so on both ends (read_csv allows specifying anything you want; you could use something like `:` maybe). if not, you will need to read the file yourself and handle creating the DataFrame yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `skipinitialspace` along with the sep:

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv",sep="," , skipinitialspace=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   name             favorites  age        other_hobbies
0   joe  [madonna, elvis, u2]   28  [football, cooking]
1  mary    [lady gaga, adele]   36                   []
```

Comment: that's cool... but how does it work? reading the docs, i would not have expected it to do that.